# Software index is broken + The application Software Updater has closed unexpectedly

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, update-manager, crash

I faced the following error message today:

> ### Software index is broken
>
> It is impossible to install or remove any software. Please use the
>   package manager "Synaptic" or run "sudo apt-get install -f" in a
>   terminal to fix this issue at first.

So I openned a terminal and typed:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

But then it crashed, I had both the output of the terminal that stuck here:

```
USER_HERE:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
USER_HERE:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up linux-headers-4.18.0-17-generic (4.18.0-17.18~18.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.7) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-16-generic
Setting up linux-headers-4.15.0-47-generic (4.15.0-47.50) ...
```

And opened a "crash report" window:

[image]

For further details:

[image]

How to fix it ?

Comment: It should work after the doing command has been run successfully.

Comment: The issue is that 2 hours later my command is still running and nothing happened since it crashed.

Comment: Reboot and try again?!?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Thanks for your reply, unfortunately I already tried :(